# replacing variables of an array in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make some sort of cryptographer, and I need to replace for ex. every "a" with "b" when the user asks for it.

```
if (DoYouWannaCrypt == 1) {
  binput.forEach(function(v, i) {
    if(v === "a") {
      input[i] = "$"
    }
  })
};
```

This works fine, however I want to add another condition that this should only be done for all 5th values of another array.

```
if (Val is 5th) {
  if (DoYouWannaCrypt == 1){
    binput.forEach(function(v, i) {
      if(v === "a") {
        input[i] = "$"
      }
    })
  }
};
```

I think you can see where I'm stuck at. I need it to work for all 5th values not just the first one.

Comment: Please don't use `<br>` as new lines. Use the markdown to style your post.

Comment: why not ask if i can be evenly divided by 5? syntax is if(i % 5 == 0)

Comment: No, I can't see where you're stuck at. What is `Val`? If `binput` is your array, your `if` is in the wrong place.

Comment: Please read this before posting other posts: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: ABove abstraction of the code should work. If something doesn't work, error is probably in your abstraction: `(Val is 5th)` and we can't see it. Maybe you should post a fiddle

Comment: @user5328504 nope, 0%5===0, and array[5] is the 6th position...

Answer (score 2):

Thats what map is for:

```
var crypted=binput.map((l,i)=>(i+1)%5?l:({"a":"$"}[l]||l));
```

http://jsbin.com/zepewituro/edit?console

Check if index (starting from 0, thats why +1 ) modulo 5 is not 0,then take the letter l, if its 0 ( then we are at the 5*n th position), then we try to replace our letter with another one, if it isnt possible fallback to the letter (||l).

Comment: OP didn’t say “for every fifth element of `binput`”, he said “for every fifth element of *another* array”.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code appears irrelevant to your problem, let me store it safely in a function first:

```
function something(binput, input, DoYouWannaCrypt) {
  if (DoYouWannaCrypt == 1)
    binput.forEach(function(v, i) {if (v === "a") input[i] = "$"});
}
```

If you want to do this operation **only for the first** element of `anotherArray`:

```
for (let Val in anotherArray)
  if (!Val) something(binput, input, DoYouWannaCrypt);
```

If you want to do it **for every** element of `anotherArray`:

```
for (let Val in anotherArray)
  something(binput, input, DoYouWannaCrypt);
```

If you want to do it **for every fifth** element of `anotherArray`:

```
for (let Val in anotherArray)
  if (!(Val%5)) something(binput, input, DoYouWannaCrypt);
```